# The bundle App.app does not support the minimum OS version specified in the Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-stickers

I'm trying to upload a Sticker Pack to app store, but I'm facing the issue

> Invalid Bundle. The bundle App.app does not support the minimum OS
>   version specified in the Info.plist

I've created a Sticker Pack project directly in XCode, and all Deployment Targets, from the App and the Sticker Extension are the same. See screenshots below. Why do I keep facing this issue? Im running last release from XCode 9.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think your problem is that you are trying to target iOS 9.0 in your app and sticker pack, when stickers weren't available until iOS 10. Can you try bumping both of them to 10 and see if you still have the same problem?